# Do we have to repeat our code in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, repeat

So I'm trying to switch from C# console to form, but I always read that never repeat our code etc.

My first project would be a calculator, and I found a site just to take a look how it looks like in win form, but in this code there are a lot of repeating. Is this normal in form, in let's say a calculator?

[Here is the link that I am talking about](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-basic-calculator-using-windows-forms-and-c-sharp/).

Comment: Pretty bad duplicate: [Refactoring Code: When to do what?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161975/1324033).

You're looking for the DRY principle, if you recognise some code can be refactored. just do it

Comment: Your question is not clear _(at least not for me)_. In a normal code you should not repeat the code _(at least not big blocks of code)_. Unfortunately the example you send is an example of 'How do not create an application' by wrong assumptions and bad coding.

Comment: Your question is arguably _How can I code this better_ which I'm not sure but I don't believe this question is suitable for SO. [ask]  It _may_ be suitable for another Stack Exchange site.  Be sure to read the site's Help Centre before posting.  Good luck

Comment: I guess you refer to the 0-9 Butrón code of that example, if you do please edit your question and add the relevante code. That being said, that code screams "Refactor me!"

Comment: "but I always read that never repeat our code" that is a good heuristic. If you can do it then you should. It is not always easy to find a structure/approach where double code can be avoided. "Is this normal in form?" what is "normal" ? It is a bad habbit. But since the link is a tutorial, they might have chosen this approach as the easiest to understand. I don't agree with that, but that is only my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of repetition, to improve it add one click event handler for all of the buttons, eg:

```
btn1.Click += btnClick;
btn2.Click += btnClick;
```

Then cast the sender to a Button to get which one was clicked, a rough example:

```
private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btnName = ((Button)sender).Name;
    var btnValue = btnName.Replace("btn",string.Empty);

    if (textBox1.Text == "0" && textBox1.Text != null)  
    {  
        textBox1.Text = btnValue;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + btnValue;  
    }  
}
```

Don't forget to unhook the event subscriptions in the form unload event:

```
btn1.Click -= btnClick;
btn2.Click -= btnClick;
```

Comment: Why is the unhooking of the events necessary? I've never done it and it never blew anything, (including memory leaks). IMO [the answers to this question say, that this is _not_ necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17108217/107625).

Comment: Can we place the magic strings "0" and "btn" in separate file?

Comment: @UweKeim its a good habit, if you don't unsubscribe events you may end up with memory leaks. The QA you linked to says the same *Unfortunately, the event architecture in .NET provides no mechanism for conveniently ensuring that events get cleaned up when objects are disposed*